# How to get a product new from and to date in phtml file in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get a product new from and to date in phtml file in magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following This way...

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
$productId = 100;
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$fromDate = $_product->getNewsFromDate();
$toDate = $_product->getNewsToDate();
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it works @rakesh

Answer (score 2):

Use object manager is not good practices. inject class instead of the object manager.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 public function getProductCollection()
{
    $productId = 1240;
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->load($productId);

    $newFromDate = collection->getNewsFromDate();
    $newToDate = collection->getNewsToDate();

}
```

You should also use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository`.

Comment: How does it differ from @Rakesh's answer?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer inject class instead of an object manager. because as per the Magento standard `EQP` you should not use object manager.

Comment: @ChiragPatel i know what is problem when using object manager but question's is not defined to using object manager or not object manager

Comment: @RakeshDonga chill man! I am just sharing this just because of new users or someone is not aware of is this. I am not posting this answer to pointing to you, but it's for all to awareness about objectmanager :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = 16  //set product id
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$putdate = $_product->getNewsFromDate();  //new from date
$putdate = $_product->getNewsToDate();  //new to date
$putdate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();  //special from date
$putdate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();  //special to date
// You can set Date format
$specntdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($putdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice explanation of how you can create a widget and display at whatever place you would like to have.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-insert-new-products-list-in-widget-magento-2.html

Let me know if you have received?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: have u misunderstand  my requirement  @sagar

Comment: i m asking about how to get  those date values in frontend